# Problems with dual boot after linux pop os installation on a windows machine

Tags: windows, dual-boot, uefi, bios, pop-os

I recently put a 128 GB SSD that i found lying around my house in my laptop. I then wanted to install `Pop OS` on it. I flashed it on a USB and did a Custom Installation.

##### The problem

I have a `boot/efi` partition on the one SSD and a `boot/efi` (of windows) on the other. I **can** boot into *Windows 10* however I **cannot** get into *Linux* OR the *BIOS*(!!!) When I press <kbd>F2</kbd> the Acer logo just goes blank and stays there forever.

I already tried to delete the `efi/boot` of Linux. I helped a bit. I can get into Windows and BIOS now. But in the BIOS I only see the Windows Boot Manager.

My laptop is the Acer Aspire 5 and I boot with UEFI.

Comment: If you have fast boot on in UEFI, that can prevent you from getting into UEFI/BIOS. You often then can only from a "cold" or full power down boot, not "warm" reboot. Acer often requires "trust" setting on the unknown entry in UEFI which is the ubuntu entry. Also if two drives you may have this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702 & step 35 for trust info  http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: @oldfred I don't think this is the case. When I don't have Linux installed, I can just go into BIOS without any problems. But as soon as I have a second EFI on my other SSD it just won't load.

Comment: As long as you only have one ESP per drive, it should be ok. But many Acer need that "trust" setting.

Comment: @oldfred Now I did it like this: Put my data that I had in my other partition D: (also on the same drive where windows is installed) and put it in my other drive. I now installed Linux in this. It least I can boot to Pop OS. Now but I still can't get into BIOS. Any advice?

Comment: Normally you cannot get into UEFI when fast boot is on. That assumes no system changes and immediately boots. No time to even press a key. Full "cold" boot or boot from total power down (and drained) will assume a normal boot where it checks what hardware you have & write that to drive for operating system to use. Then you just have time to press a key. Microsoft required vendors to add fast boot, and boot SSDs and used fast start up/hibernation as Windows booted so slow. If not making changes you can have fast boot on. Some systems have fast boot settings for a slight delay.

Comment: @oldfred I already turned it off before the installation. Any other adive? :(

Comment: Are you sure you fully removed all power, if battery laptop remove it and hold power switch for at least 10 sec to drain all power. Otherwise you have to remove coin battery on motherboard or jumper pins on motherboard to totally reset UEFI settings. And then redo all changes you made in UEFI settings.You need vendor manual on system for all that.